# VsCode not supporting EJS

Tags: visual-studio-code, ejs

VsCode is not supporting EJS in the dropdown when I try to create a file. I have the EJS language support extension and I used the setting configuration that was suggested on similar questions, yet it is still not working. I saw one website saying this solution no longer works on current versions of VsCode. Is there a known solution to this? Here are my setting configurations.

Edit: My mistake was my own misunderstanding. I thought I would need to save my files as an EJS file via the dropdown but saving as an html and embedding the tags was all I needed. Hope this helps someone else.

````
    "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Abyss",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Tomorrow Night Blue",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase",
    "[html]": {

        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    },
    "files.associations": {
        "*.ejs": "html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "ejs": "html",
    },
    "html.format.templating": true
}```
````